# How to interpret the 0 esimtated value in semi-log regression model

Tags: r, regression

I am new to R studio. I tried to use the regression model.
I used the semi-log model due to the normality.

I summarised the results of the regression. And I found that two variables (called v1 and v2) had 0 predict (estimate) values. V1 and V2 are continuous variables as the control variables. And I used the independent variable (categorical variable), and the dependent variable (continuous variable). The r-squared value increased when adding v1 and v2. According to their p-value, they are statistically significant. I am confused why they had 0 predicted value and I don't know how to interpret them. If you have any advice, please inform me about it.

The following picture is the summary table of the regression model that I mentioned.

[image]

And This is the regression result.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you mean that there were zero estimated values? Aren't the coefficient estimates $8.307\times 10^{-4}$ and $9.636\times 10^{-4}?$

Comment: I mean the 0 value in the summary table of the regression :) I think the table uses the 2 digits so it is expressed as 0 value (8.307×10−4 and 9.636×10−4). I wonder which one is the proper interpretation (considering the result of the regression model, V1 and V2 had a positive association with the house cost. V1 and V2 increased 0.08% and 0.09%, respectively or V1 and V2 are not meaningful due to the 0 estimated values in summary table although they had statistical significant (p<0.05)). I am struggle how to interpret them in correct way.

Comment: If both interpretations that I wrote, please inform me about how to interpret the regression model.

Comment: The estimates are *not* zeros, as the output plainly shows: the zeros in the first table merely round the estimates of `8.307e-04` (which is $0.0008307$) and `9.636e-04` to two decimal places.  There's nothing special about the interpretation, but if you want to persuade your *software* to print the table with adequate precision, consider re-expressing the values of `V1` and `V2`. For instance, if you were to divide them both by $10^6,$ their estimates would be *multiplied* by $10^6,$ placing them in the high hundreds.

Answer (score 6):

The `R` printout shows your regression coefficients to be estimated as $8.307 \times 10^{-4} = 0.0008307$ and $9.636 \times 10^{-4} = 0.0009636$. These values have the usual interpretation as regression coefficients with a logged target variable (the usual business about percent change).

Then the upper table shows that, when the coefficients are rounded to two decimal places, both round to zero, which is correct rounding. This is a valid criticism of the table using rounding.

You are able to get significance of those seemingly tiny coefficients because, perhaps among other reasons, you have thousands of observations that give considerable statistical power and ability to detect small effect sizes. You are within your rights as a scientist (economist, physician, engineer, etc), however, to say that, despite the statistical significance, those small values have no practical significance and are essentially zero, or you might use your knowledge of the subject to say that such a magnitude really does matter. However, separate the statistical significance from the practical importance; statistical significance does not necessarily make something interesting.

Comment: These aren't necessarily "tiny" coefficients, because there is no basis for comparing their magnitudes.  These might be practically *huge* coefficients, merely expressed in large units!

Comment: @whuber Right, André the Giant was a small number of parsecs tall.

Comment: Nice example!  I always watch out for such problems in real estate analyses because real estate prices (and related amounts like annual taxes, *etc.*) when expressed in nominal currency units like dollars, Euros, Yen, *etc.* tend to be large enough that coefficients attached to them can be so small that non-scientific software will round them away to nothing. So, although I have no idea what `V1` or `V2` might be, my antennae are already up... .

Comment: Many Thank you for your comments. I could catch how to interpret them. V1 is the fuel cost, and V2 is the internet cost, which are included in the house rent price :) I forgot the change the variables name

Comment: I think the reason why V1 and V2 have almost 0 values is the different unit from the dependent variables. I used the semi-log regression model. So I changed the dependent variable (house price) to log10. However, the independent variable and control variables did not change. Consequently, the dependent variable is the log value, while V1 and V2 are the real price (pounds).

Comment: In this case, could I interpret them as “although their p values are under 0.05, they are statistically insignificant due to the small effect size” ? Or should I change V1 and V2 to log?

Comment: If your definition of statistical significance is that the p-value is less than $0.05$ (or even $0.0001$), then there is statistical significance. What there might not be is practical significance. That judgment is based on your knowledge of the subject. @user21268575

Comment: I am concerned that if changed the values, the regression model becomes commingled (seems like combines the log-log model and semi-log model).

Comment: @user21268575 I do not follow what you mean about changing the values. Perhaps that warrants it’s own posted question.